# Calculate this integral $\int \int_{R^2}x^2e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

So I find myself stuck on this integral where $R^2$ is the real plane:

$$\int\int_{R^2}x^2e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$

I know I'm suposed to perform some variable substitution but I just don't see it. Polar coordinates got me nothing but trouble. When I try that path I end up with something looking like this:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos{2\theta}+1)d\theta\int_0^\infty \frac{r^3}{e^r}dr$$

In which the second integral gives me grief.

Comment: Hint: using $\int x^2 e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{1}{2}\int (x^2+y^2) e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ avoids angular integrals. To calculate the second integral use integration by parts (three times): $\int r^3 e^{-r} dr = [-r^3 e^{-r}]_0^\infty + \int 3r^2 e^{-r} dr $

Comment: I forgot the second integral in my question which I've edited now. 

Do you still mean that x and y are symmetric?

Comment: Don't know why I didn't consider triple partial integration, that would obviously work. Thanks!

Comment: Try to do it in general (it is just as easy): define $I_n = \int_0^\infty r^n e^{-r} dr$ and use integration by parts to show that $I_n = n I_{n-1}$. Togeather with $I_0 = 1$ we get $I_n = n!$. For more info see the wiki for the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm glad I posted this trivial question, got such an interesting reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's been a long week but thanks to Winther I realised that it is possible to continue with my integral after polar coordinate substitution using partial integration thrice:

$$ \pi\int_0^\infty \frac{r^3}{e^r}dr=\pi\Big(\big[-e^{-r}r^3\big]^\infty_0 +3\int_0^\infty\frac{r^2}{e^r}dr\Big)=\\ =\pi\Big(\big[-e^{-r}r^3\big]^\infty_0+\big[-3e^{-r}r^2\big]^\infty_0+6\int_0^\infty\frac{r}{e^r}dr\Big)=\\
=\pi\Big(\big[-e^{-r}r^3\big]^\infty_0+\big[-3e^{-r}r^2\big]^\infty_0+\big[-6e^{-r}r\big]^\infty_0+6\int_0^\infty e^{-r}dr\Big)=$$

$$=\pi\Big(-0+0+3\times0-3\times0-6\times0+6\times0-6\times0+6\Big)=6\pi.  $$